# Azure Web App for Django Deployment Not Working

Tags: django, azure, environment-variables, settings, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Django React web app using Azure, but it's not running. I'm using GitHub to push the code onto Azure, so I think the issue is in my settings.py file. For security reasons, I stored the SECRET_KEY, DATABASES, ALLOWED_HOSTS, and DEBUG settings in a .env file and did not push that onto GitHub. On the Azure app, I went into the application settings and tried to add those variables in but I think there's an issue with that. Does anyone know how to properly add those environmental variables, especially the DATABASES settings for a MySQL server?

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you did not ignore the .env file in the .gitignore**

*In order to connect Django with the Mysql server. You Follow this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database).*

sample code to configure MySQL server.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

If you are using Linux virtual machine.

*create a file my.cnf* at folder '/etc/mysql/' using command

`sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

add database credentials into the file.

```
database = blog_data
user = djangouser
password = your_actual_password
default-character-set = utf8
```